# multiple objects per set type are not allowed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Based on the [Microsoft Walkthrough on test-driven development with entity framework 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/12/17/walkthrough-test-driven-development-with-the-entity-framework-4-0.aspx) I have made the repository pattern in our MVC4 application to be able to do unit tests.

I've created a `IContext` interface which looks like this:

```
public interface IContext : IDisposable
{

    // This interface represents all the important operations on our ObjectContext 
    // (which is in Context.cs). Now our tests can work against 
    // the interface rather than against the concrete object type, which will make 
    // it easier for us to substitute a fake Context. Substituting a fake means 
    // we can remove the need to interact with the database, which will speed up the 
    // test and eliminate the hassle of needing to reset the database to its initial 
    // state after each test run.

    IDbSet<Product> Products { get; }
    IDbSet<Shop> Shops { get; }
    IDbSet<User> Users { get; }
    IDbSet<Order> Orders { get; }
    IDbSet<Cart> Carts { get; }
    IDbSet<Category> Categories { get; }
    IDbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; }

    int SaveChanges();
}
```

Besides this the "real" context inherits from this IContext and looks like this:

```
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

    IDbSet<Product> ICorveeContext.Products
    {
        get { return this.Products; }
    }

    IDbSet<Shop> ICorveeContext.Shops
    {
        get { return this.Shops; }
    }

    IDbSet<User> ICorveeContext.Users
    {
        get { return this.Users; }
    }

    IDbSet<Order> ICorveeContext.Orders
    {
        get { return this.Orders; }
    }

    IDbSet<Cart> ICorveeContext.Carts
    {
        get { return this.Carts; }
    }

    IDbSet<Category> ICorveeContext.Categories
    {
        get { return this.Categories; }
    }

    IDbSet<Transaction> ICorveeContext.Transactions
    {
        get { return this.Transactions; }
    }
```

Then I have one test to test if the OrderController works;

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void IndexTest()
    {
        OrderController orderController = new OrderController();
        ActionResult result = orderController.Index();
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));
    }
```

This test fails and gives the following message:

```
Test method Project.Tests.Controllers.OrderControllerTest.IndexTest threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object 
sets 'Products' and 'Project.Models.IContext.Products' can [sic?] both contain instances of 
 type 'Project.Models.Product'.
```

Why is this the case? I did everything according to this repository pattern but it just does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because DbContext automatically initializes all the `IDbSet<T>` properties.
This is why you can have `public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }` without having to worry to initialize it in your constructor by calling `this.Products = this.Set<Product>();`

Now, you have duplicate properties for your tables (`DbSet<Product>` and `IDbSet<Product>`), since `DbSet<Product>` implements `IDbSet<Product>`, the context sets initializer fails.

I would suggest exposing your repositories as `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IDbSet<T>`

Since `IQueryable<T>` does not expose the Add, Remove and other great methods I would create another interface and class to wrap your `IDbSet<T>`.

**UPDATE:**
I would implement your interface a little bit different. I will only implement one table for demo purposes.

```
public class DbContextWrapper : IContext, IDisposable
{
  private MyDbContext _context;

  public DbContextWrapper()
  {
    this._context = new MyDbContext();
  }

  IDbSet<Product> IContext.Products
  {
    get { return this._context.Products; }
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    this._context.Dispose();
  }
}
```

This way you don't have a conflict when the DbContext is trying to initialize your `DbSet`s.
Remember to remove your `IDbSet` properties from your DbContext class.

Comment: `I would suggest exposing your repositories as IQueryable<T> instead of IDbSet<T>`
That is a possibility, but then the following method:

       public void AddShop(Shop s)
        {
            _context.Shops.Add(s);
        }

does not work because .Add does not exist. How do I add stuff to context with an IQueryAble. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: `Since IQueryable<T> does not expose the Add, Remove and other great methods I would create another interface and class to wrap your IDbSet<T>.` Hmm, how does this work?

Comment: @ArturoMartinz where do I connect the wrapper class with the 'real' context class?

Comment: As you can see the constructor of the wrapper now initializes the constructor and your IDbSet of Products in your wrapper returns the DbSet in your real context

Comment: I did something that resembles this based on the [repository pattern](http://joel.net/repository-and-unit-of-work-for-entity-framework-ef4-for-unit-testing). The only problem now is that the solution does no compile since the methods `Entry` and `SaveChanges`, are not defined. Especially the `Entry` one (e.g., context.Entry(object)) is bothering me.

Comment: Since this is a wrapper you can also wrap those 2 methods

Answer (score 1):

You have exposed the `IDbSet` properties as public but also exposed the concrete `DbSet` fields as public.  Change the storage fields to `private`:

```
private DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
private DbSet<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
private DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
private DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
private DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
private DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
private DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
```

And figure out how else to "set" the data from outside the class.  Constructor?  public methods?

Comment: This is a possibility but then I need to change a lot of code to use getters and setters instead of just Context.Add(blabla)...